# Qt's application wide stylesheet not overwritten by local default stylesheet

Tags: css, qt, qtstylesheets

I have an application which loads a .qss styling file and apply the stylesheet to the whole application. My problem is that it modifies the default `QGroupBox` styling instead of a subclass of it, and I would like a default-style `QGroupBox` in one place.
Here is an example of the styling applied application wide that I'm trying to replace by the default one.

```
QGroupBox {
    border: 0px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid block;
}
```

I have tried to reset the stylesheet by using

```
_ui->setupUi(this);
_ui->myGroupBox->setStylesheet("");
```

But this does not work. From what I've gathered, the application-wide styling should have happened duing the `setupUi()` phase though, and thus be overwritten by the empty (default) stylesheet. This does not seem to be the case.

I have also tried without success to set it directly from Qt Designer, or from the qss file using.

```
myGroupBox {
}
```

However, if I put `border-bottom: 1px solid red;` in the qss file, it is correctly registered and overrule the default style. I do not now the default parameters though, so I cannot set them all by hand if needed.

If I remove the annoying qss rule, it works fine, but it breaks the application ui in 50 other places and I sadly do not have the time to refactor it right now.

Am I missing something when it comes to resetting to the default stylesheet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up the **styles** with style**sheets**. These are different beasts. When a widget has a stylesheet, it is not styled by the style mechanism anymore, because the styles in general aren't flexible enough to be modified by stylesheets, since they e.g. depend on platform-provided images etc. The two mechanisms are exclusive of each other: either one can control the appearance of the widget, but once you use a stylesheet, it's all-or-nothing: the style mechanism is out of the picture.

Simply fix your stylesheet to apply only to the group boxes it should apply to - you can select them by name or name path.

Comment: Thanks, I did it the hard and correct way, and subclassed the QGroupBox to apply the stylesheet in the qss to this subclass only. Creating individual rules would have been way to complicated, there was a couple hundred of  them. Took some time, but probably better in the end.